# How to get only valid url links while parsing a page with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, url

I am trying to get a list of pages that a page is linking to (using  tag). When parsing the page I use BeautifulSoup:

```
page = opener.open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), features='lxml')
links = soup.findAll("a", href=True)
for link in links:
    validLink = bool(re.match(r'^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)', link["href"]))
    if validLink:
         myset.append(link["href"])
```

This way it looks for `<a href>` tags to find the links and return the **url** of the linked page. But the resulting urls in **myset** look like this:

[image]

How can I filter the links that have **hash sign** in them? Also if I wanted to filter **ad links** or **videos**,... which element of the tag should I use?

Comment: If you want to get all URLs that start with `http`, just use `if link["href"].startswith('http'):
         myset.append(link["href"])`

Comment: `if validLink and link['href'][0] != '#'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For link that start with http or https (you only need to state the http) you can use attribute selector with start with operator

```
links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('[href^=http]')]
```

For ad links/video - do you wish to include or exclude? We will need to see the relevant html. Is there an url to use?